# -İnfinty value returned

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want calculate a object's attribute but this code return -infinity value. how do ı fix this ?

```
 etki1 = singleton.kartlistesib1[sayi4].etki()
 etki2 = singleton.kartlistesib2[sayi4].etki();
 sayi6 = singleton.kartlistesib1[sayi4].dayanıklılık - etki1/(8/10)*etki2;
 sayi7 = singleton.kartlistesib2[sayi4].dayanıklılık - etki2/(8/10)*etki1;
```

ı tried many method but i cant

Comment: Without knowing what these variables are, and how they are set, it is impossible to say. Please post more code.

Comment: what is the return value you except? do you set breakpoint to check if each variable's value is excepted.